# Center div position

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I try to display images in six separate div's . All div are placed with correct position .but center div position look likes one is going upward and other center div is going downward i also post image so you better to understand what i trying to say and also i post HTML and CSS code .. [image](http://oi61.tinypic.com/1tagdv.jpg)

```css
       .cat_section {
         text-align: center;
       }
       .cateogry_div {
         display: inline-block;
         float: none;
         background-image: url('http://elemisdesign.com/img/114/1.jpg');
         width: 300px;
         height: 200px;
         margin-top: 90px;
         margin-left: 30px;
       }
       .sub_category {
         margin-left: 30px;
         margin-top: 10px;
       }
       .image_cat {
         width: 170px;
         margin-left: 90px;
       }
       .sub_category span {
         font-size: 20px;
         float: right;
         margin-right: 180px;
         margin-top: -90px;
         width: 110px;
         height: 120px;
       }
       .cateogry_div1 {
         display: inline-block;
         float: none;
         background-image: url('http://elemisdesign.com/img/114/1.jpg');
         width: 300px;
         height: 200px;
         margin-top: 90px;
         margin-left: 40px;
       }
       .cateogry_div2 {
         display: inline-block;
         float: none;
         background-image: url('http://elemisdesign.com/img/114/1.jpg');
         width: 300px;
         height: 200px;
         margin-top: 90px;
         margin-left: 50px;
       }
       .cateogry_div3 {
         display: inline-block;
         float: none;
         background-image: url('http://elemisdesign.com/img/114/1.jpg');
         width: 300px;
         height: 200px;
         margin-top: 90px;
         margin-left: 30px;
       }
       .cateogry_div4 {
         display: inline-block;
         float: none;
         background-image: url('http://elemisdesign.com/img/114/1.jpg');
         width: 300px;
         height: 200px;
         margin-top: 150px;
         margin-left: 40px;
       }
       .cateogry_div5 {
         display: inline-block;
         float: none;
         background-image: url('http://elemisdesign.com/img/114/1.jpg');
         width: 300px;
         height: 200px;
         margin-top: 90px;
         margin-left: 50px;
       }
```

```html
<div class="cat_section">
  <div class="cateogry_div">
    <div class="sub_category">
      <img class="image_cat" src="images/watch.jpg" />
      <span>Handwatches</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="cateogry_div1">
    <div class="sub_category">
      <img class="image_cat" src="images/pocket_purse.jpg" />
      <span>Pocket</span>
      <br />
      <span>Purse</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="cateogry_div2">
    <div class="sub_category">
      <img class="image_cat" src="images/rings.jpg" />
      <span>Rings</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="cateogry_div3">
    <div class="sub_category">
      <img class="image_cat" src="images/bangles.jpeg" />
      <span>Bangles</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="cateogry_div4">
    <div class="sub_category">
      <img class="image_cat" src="images/sunglasses.jpeg" />
      <span>Sun glasses</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="cateogry_div5">
    <div class="sub_category">
      <img class="image_cat" src="images/clutch.jpeg" />
      <span>Clutch</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Any help ?

Comment: They are all perfectly aligned. Check your own snippet in full page mode.

Comment: This can be done more fluid and responsive, but that is another question. My answer below solves this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add**

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to your `.category_div` containers and **remove**

```
margin-top: 150px;
```

from `.category_div4` (put 90px, the same as all the rest)

Answer (score 0):

You are using br tag between span of pocket purse, that's the reason, **Remove br between span of pocket and purse**

**HTML**

```
<div class="cateogry_div1">
 <div class="sub_category">
     <img class="image_cat" src="images/pocket_purse.jpg" /> <span>Pocket</span>  <span>Purse</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fo0bnd65/1/)

Comment: i remove br tag "pocket purses" div placed correctly but still sun glasses div position not correct

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different answer that involves restructuring some of the HTML & CSS. This code might be a little more stable for getting the layout you are after.

Here is a [JSFiddle of the answer](https://jsfiddle.net/j93nsbrp/).

***Note:*** Just replace the `http://placehold.it/170x170` placeholder images with your own.

### HTML

```
<div class="cat_section">
    <div class="category" id="cateogry_div">
        <div class="sub_category">
            <img class="image_cat" src="http://placehold.it/170x170" /> 
            <p>Handwatches</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category" id="category_div1">
        <div class="sub_category">
            <img class="image_cat" src="http://placehold.it/170x170" /> 
            <p>Pocket<br />Purse</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category" id="category_div2">
        <div class="sub_category">
            <img class="image_cat" src="http://placehold.it/170x170" /> 
            <p>Rings</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category" id="category_div3">
        <div class="sub_category">
            <img class="image_cat" src="http://placehold.it/170x170" /> 
            <p>Bangles</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category" id="category_div4">
        <div class="sub_category">
            <img class="image_cat" src="http://placehold.it/170x170" />
            <p>Sun glasses</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category" id="category_div5">
        <div class="sub_category">
            <img class="image_cat" src="http://placehold.it/170x170" />
            <p>Clutch</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
   .cat_section {
       text-align: center;
   }
   .category {
       display: block;
       float: left;
       background-image: url('http://elemisdesign.com/img/114/1.jpg');
       width: 300px;
       height: 200px;
       margin-top: 90px;
       margin-left: 30px;
   }
   .sub_category {
       /*margin-left: 30px;
       margin-top: 10px;*/
       padding: 10px;
   }
   .image_cat {
       float: right;
       width: 170px;
       margin-left: 10px;
   }
   .sub_category p {
       float: right;
       width: 100px;
       padding-top: 50px;
       font-size: 20px;
   }
```

Comment: No problem - have a look through the code and see if you can make your version a bit more stable.  :)