# margin values not working for a div with float none property

Tags: html, css

I wanted to center a div. i did so with margin and float property..but the margin values is not working properly

```css
.body {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.content {
  width: 70px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  float: none;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.content p{float:left;margin:0;}
```

```html
<div class="body">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="content"><p>hello all<p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here the margin top and bottom values(i.e 10px) is not working properly..margin bottom value is commencing from the top which should have from the bottom!

Comment: The div is in center. What you issue is

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32371990/center-div-position)

Comment: Do you mean there is an extra space on top of the `.body`?

Comment: ive edited the code...now change the margin values i.e top and bottom values and see from where it commences

Comment: try `.content { overflow:hidden; }`

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to center with float as it takes the element out of the normal document flow. Center with margin 'auto' instead.

HTML

```
 <div class="body">
   <div class="content">hello all</div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .body{
  width: 100%;
 }
 .content{
 display:block;
 width: 70px;
 margin: 10px auto;
 }
```

Comment: centering is not issue here..when we change the margin top and bottom values..especially margin bottom value, it starts from above instead of below

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
body{
 margin:0px;
}

.container{
   width: 100%;
}
.content{
   display:block;
   width: 70px;
   margin: 10px auto;
}
```